# Rails 4 - problems with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I'm having an inordinate amount of trouble using a nested model with `fields_for` in a form. Specifically, not all of the nested fields save. A User has many Experiences, but when I submit the form, an Experience with the correct `user_id` but NO CONTENT is inserted into the database.

Looking at the logs, I also get an error:

```
unpermitted parameters: experience.
```

[Rails 4 nested attributes not saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711556/rails-4-nested-attributes-not-saving) doesn't help, unfortunately.

Here's the code:

**SCHEMA**

```
create_table "experiences", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "content",    null: false, default: ""
  t.integer  "user_id"
end
```

**MODEL**

```
#user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :experiences
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :experiences


#experience.rb
class Experience < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.experiences.build
end

def update
  @user = current_user
  @user.experiences.build
  @user.update!(user_params)
  redirect_to root_path
end

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, 
    :password_confirmation, :title, :blurb, :city, :state, 
    :style_list, :experience_attributes => [:id, :content])
end
```

**VIEW**

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <!-- (Omitted) user fields -->
  <%= f.fields_for :experience do |experience_fields| %>
    <%= experience_fields.text_field :content, placeholder: 'Content' %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit 'Edit profile' %>
<% end %>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a `create` method in your controller? Currently i cant see it in the Code which you posted.

Comment: And also you are not permitted `user_id`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

```
@user.experiences.build # -> note "experience**s**"
```

This means when you use `fields_for`, you have to reference `:experiences` (you're currently referencing the singular):

```
  <%= f.fields_for :experiences do |experience_fields| %>
    <%= experience_fields.text_field :content, placeholder: 'Content' %>
  <% end %>
```

This also goes for your `strong_params`:

```
params.require(:user).permit(experiences_attributes: [:id, :content])
```

Comment: Wow.I didn't see that.Now it makes sense.What about not permitting `user_id`.I think it create problems.

Comment: `user_id` will be passed automatically. The question even stated the `user_id` field was being filled by the controller. I only saw it because I've spent DAYS fixing an error like this before!