# api saving multiple children records only save one with missing fields ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-api

Making an api call that has on it a parent record (which is item) and children records (which are photos) the item record get saved fine, but the images it only save one image with missing fields.

Here is the json im sending

```
{"item_category": "Books & Magazines", "item_condition": "Used",
"item_name": "Crushing it", "summary": "super awesome",
"price": 20, "active": true,"instant": 1,
"access_token": "p8Z-yZ1wRooBLsZj4yeS",
"photo_attributes":
[{"created_at": "2019-05-16 05:28:16.696408",
"image_file_name": "images.jpg",
"image_content_type": "image/jpeg","image_file_size": 257908,
"image_updated_at":"2019-05-21 15:20:55.390445"},
{"created_at": "2019-05-16 05:28:16.696408",
"image_file_name": "images.jpg",
"image_content_type": "image/jpeg","image_file_size": 257908,
"image_updated_at":"2019-05-21 15:20:55.390445"}
]}
```

this is the api im calling

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/createitem
```

here is image of the command line
[image]

as you see here the item got saved 
[image]

as you see here it only took one image with 3 fields
[image]

this items.contoller.rb

```
 class Api::V1::ItemsController < ApplicationController
 def createitem
   @item = current_user.items.new(item_params)
   if @item.save 
     render json: @item, status: :ok
   else
     render json: { error: "Something went wrong", is_success: false}, status: 422
   end
 end
 def item_params
       params.require(:item).permit(:item_category, :item_condition,:item_name,:summary,:address,:price,:active, :instant, photo_attributes:[:created_at, :image_file_size, :image_updated_at, :image_file_name, :image_content_type])
  end
 end
```

this is the item.rb model

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
enum instant: {Request: 0, Instant: 1}

belongs_to :user
has_many :photos
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos

validates :item_category, presence: true
validates :item_condition, presence: true
end
```

I tired this solution but still did not save any photo
[Rails 4 nested attributes not saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711556/rails-4-nested-attributes-not-saving)

here is the update items.controller.rb

```
class Api::V1::ItemsController < ApplicationController
 def createitem
   @item = current_user.items.build(item_params)
   @item.photos.each do |photo|
     photo.build
   end
   if @item.save 
     render json: @item, status: :ok
   else
     render json: { error: "Something went wrong", is_success: false}, status: 422
   end
 end
 def item_params
   params.require(:item).permit(:item_category, :item_condition,:item_name,:summary,:address,:price,:active, :instant, photos_attributes:[:created_at, :image_file_size, :image_updated_at, :image_file_name, :image_content_type])
  end
 end
```

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711556/rails-4-nested-attributes-not-saving

Comment: @iGian i updated my question the solution there did not work

Answer (score 0):

First your json should be

```
{"item_category": "Books & Magazines", "item_condition": "Used",
"item_name": "Crushing it", "summary": "super awesome",
"price": 20, "active": true,"instant": 1,
"access_token": "p8Z-yZ1wRooBLsZj4yeS",
"photo_attributes":
[{"created_at": "2019-05-16 05:28:16.696408",
"image_file_name": "images.jpg",
"image_content_type": "image/jpeg","image_file_size": 257908,
"image_updated_at":"2019-05-21 15:20:55.390445"},
{"created_at": "2019-05-16 05:28:16.696408",
"image_file_name": "images.jpg",
"image_content_type": "image/jpeg","image_file_size": 257908,
"image_updated_at":"2019-05-21 15:20:55.390445"}
]}
```

and second update the

```
def item_params
   params.require(:item).permit(:item_category, :item_condition,:item_name,:summary,:address,:price,:active, :instant, photos_attributes:[:created_at, :image_file_size, :image_updated_at, :image_file_name, :image_content_type])
end
```

with

```
def item_params
   params.require(:item).permit(:item_category, :item_condition,:item_name,:summary,:address,:price,:active, :instant, photo_attributes:[:created_at, :image_file_size, :image_updated_at, :image_file_name, :image_content_type])
```

end

and create method with

```
def create
 @item = current_user.items.new(item_params)
   if @item.save 
     render json: @item, status: :ok
   else
     render json: { error: "Something went wrong", is_success: false}, status: 422
   end
 end
```

Comment: I updated items.controller.rb of u told me but it still does not save any photo record and it does not throw any error, I updated the question to of what u gave me

Comment: Did you updated the json also to `photo_attributes` instead of `photos_attributes`

Answer (score 0):

changing the item_parms def fixed the issue

```
def item_params
 params[:item][:photos_attributes] = params[:photos_attributes]
 params.require(:item).permit(:item_category, :item_condition,:item_name,:summary,:address,:price,:active, :instant, photos_attributes:[:image_file_size, :image_updated_at, :image_file_name, :image_content_type])
end
```

i got my answer from here

[Rails 5.1 API - how to permit params for nested JSON object's attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46853637/rails-5-1-api-how-to-permit-params-for-nested-json-objects-attributes)